# enable tls on visual studio c#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, ssl

On the drop down methods available for SmtpClient only includes EnableSsl but not tls.

> What are the steps to enable tls on visio studio c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS is just another name for SSL past v3; absent a version number, they mean basically the same thing. Note that the built-in SMTP Client only supports `STARTTLS` style secured connections, and not SMTPS (the one that uses its own separate port). If you need SMTPS support you'll need to go find a third-party SMTP client or roll your own.